# Why do I a get different cut-off frequency in LTspice?

Tags: filter, ltspice, low-pass

I have built a low-pass filter circuit according to the multifeedback topology using the values for the resistors and capacitors calculated with the help of [this website](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPttool.php).

[image: Circuit Website]

According to the website, the cutoff frequency should be about 95 Hz.

I built the same circuit, with the corresponding values for the resistors and capacitors in LTspice.  The simulation gives a different cutoff frequency.

The supply voltage U+ and U- are at +2.5V and -2.5V.

[image: Circuit LT-Spice]

[image: Simulation LT-Spice]

My guess is that the simulations use different op-amps to calculate the frequency response, but I'm not sure.

Comment: A cutoff frequency is at -3dB, you are showing -6dB.

Comment: I know, but i wanted to show, that the 95 Hz are at -6dB and not like calculated at -3db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The op-amp characteristics are not considered in the web page calculator.

If you change the Q to 0.707 (or the damping ratio to 0.707, this is the point where the two are equal) you'll get much closer to -3dB at the characteristic frequency using that calculator. That should be Butterworth response.

You can also pick E96 series resistors to get closer, but that's not the main issue here.

Comment: You were completely right, the dumping factor was the problem